# Raspbian-compatible JavaScript IDE

Tags: node.js, arm, ide

Does anyone know of any JavaScript IDEs (or IDEs that support JS) that can be compiled or installed on Raspberry Pi?

I've found a few good IDEs that are compilable/installable on the pi, but most of them are python. Also I am able to use javascript with a standard text editor but I'm looking for a more feature-rich IDE.

I haven't been able to find one so far and I probably won't ever find one but I'm asking here just in case someone knows of one  ;).

Comment: your question is not related to the RPi .... it is a linux question

Comment: @jsotola Not completely. First, I'm looking for an ARM-compatible IDE and second, I'm looking for a IDE that is computationally inexpensive and doesn't use much memory, so that it can run smoothly on the pi.

Comment: @jsotala, Raspbian is a Linux and question is highly related to RPI because Raspbian is made just for RPI. I am developing Javascript on Geany editor that is fast and fantastic so far on Raspbian, but it would be fine to have more than highlighting.